Firebase Messaging getToken() Error: Invalid fetch response
firebase token error while running in ios
FLTFirebaseMessaging: An error occurred while calling method Messaging#getToken, errorOrNil => {
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Invalid fetch response, expected 'token' or 'Error' key";
}


Please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/79140368/4373661

This question is similar to: "Firebase Messaging getToken() Error: Invalid fetch response, expected 'token' or 'Error' key" in ios app. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Verify your Firebase Project Configuration
Re-download google-services.json (For Android) or GoogleService-Info.plist (For iOS)
For Android, Required permissions are declared in the AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

For iOS, required capabilities and permissions in your Info.plist
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>

app/build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.3.0')
}

Please Verify Your gettoken function:
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
String? token = await messaging.getToken();
print("FCM Token: $token");

or
try {
  String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  print("FCM Token: $token");
} catch (e) {
  print("Error fetching FCM token: $e");
}

if above all steps perfect.
then test your stable network connection.
